# Is there a faster method of deleting shapes in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've successfully added shapes into cells (msoShapeOval) in a pivot table. 
I need to clear and recreate these shapes if the pivot / slicer selection changes. 
My current method works, but it is slow. 
Is there any better method to clear shapes in bulk? 
Note: I do know the exact cell range where all these shapes exist. 
I've also appied :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Current code:

```
  Dim Shp as Shape
  For Each Shp In rng.Parent.Shapes
     If InStrB(Shp.Name, "$") > 0 Then Shp.Delete
  Next
```

Comment: did you try `rng.Parent.Shapes.delete` ?

Comment: @jsotola. Thanks. However, I have some shapes (Slicers) that I do not want to delete, hence the restriction in the code to shapes with cell references

Comment: record a macro. .... start the recorder, insert a few shapes into a worksheet, group them, then delete the group .... the resulting code may point you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to delete the shapes at once without selecting, with some fine tuning. Let's imagine you want to delete the rectangulars from this:

[image]

What you need to do is the following:

- loop through all the objects
- make an array with all the rectangular's names
- delete the objects in the array

Tricky part is the looping through the objects, because you need to increment your array every time, which is not a built-in functionality (like in collection). `incrementArray` is the function for this.

Furthermore, the first time you increment to the unassigned array, you need to check whether it is allocated (achieved with the `IsArrayAllocated` function below).

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim shp             As Shape
    Dim arrOfShapes()   As Variant 'the () are important!

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If InStrB(shp.Name, "Rec") > 0 Then
                arrOfShapes = incrementArray(arrOfShapes, shp.Name)
            End If
        Next
        If IsArrayAllocated(arrOfShapes) Then
            Debug.Print .Shapes.Range(arrOfShapes(0)).Name
            .Shapes.Range(arrOfShapes).Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The additional functions:

```
Public Function incrementArray(arrOfShapes As Variant, nameOfShape As String) As Variant

    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim arrNew      As Variant

    If IsArrayAllocated(arrOfShapes) Then
        ReDim arrNew(UBound(arrOfShapes) + 1)            
        For cnt = LBound(arrOfShapes) To UBound(arrOfShapes)
            arrNew(cnt) = CStr(arrOfShapes(cnt))
        Next cnt
        arrNew(UBound(arrOfShapes) + 1) = CStr(nameOfShape)
    Else
        arrNew = Array(nameOfShape)
    End If

    incrementArray = arrNew

End Function

Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                       Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                       LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)

End Function
```

Credits to [this guy](https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/properly-declare-variable-when-working-with-shapes-range-in-excel/) for the finding that the `arrOfShapes` should be declared with parenthesis (I have spent about 30 minutes researching why I could not pass it correctly) and to [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx) for the `IsArrayAllocated()`.

Comment: Thanks! Another brilliant solution! I think there is just too much data to handle in my example, so I'll need to try an alternative to shapes. I had tried storing shape data in an array but was getting nowhere! Now I know how!

Comment: @MiguelH - I was trying to delete the `arrOfShapes` for about 30 minutes, before I saw the article of dutchgemini and simply added the parenthesis!

Comment: Nice work.  I wanted to use an array but I didn't know how. +1

Comment: I see what you mean about needing to declare a Variant Array.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - yup. Obviously the dutchgemini guy was having the same problem about 7 years ago :)

Comment: @ThomasInzina I found the google drive example above far more efficient than your other solution, so if you want to add this as an answer, I'll up vote it too. I ran into "DrawingShape" issues with your other solution once I applied it to multiple sheets. Not too sure why though!

Comment: @MiguelH Vityata has the correct answer I just refactored it.  I'm going to delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all shapes except slicers:

```
Sub RemoveAllExceptSlicers()

    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not sh.Type = MsoShapeType.msoSlicer Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JohnyL, but this is essentially what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: You could use `F5` -> `Special...` -> `Objects`. This will select all shapes. Then unselect slicers and press `Del` :)

Comment: Great idea! However, the macro runs out of continuation character space (There are 2,000+ shapes!)